# JobPosting structured data if user input is incomplete/incorrect

Tags: rich-snippets, structured-data

I have a job portal job website that lets employers post their vacancies. My question is regarding some information required to generate the structured data for search engines and in specific for the

```
jobLocation.address.postalCode
```

What if the employer just entered random numbers or incorrect postal code? Does that affects the website and let Google hits it with a penalty? Without entering such value the `JobPosting` would receive a warning and it seems that it's not being processed into a rich card at least effectively.

Is it okay to enter a value like "NA" when the employer leaves it blank? Or "Confidential" in case the employer wants to keep their data private?. This is an issue when I rely on 3rd party to enter data.

Comment: [Question without the SEO part on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50778107/1591669)

Comment: It is almost exactly the same. Cross posted.

Comment: I thought those forums are separated especially that I receievd a note that it should be here.

Comment: Beside thag I don't know much here how to delete a post, I'm sorry; if you could delete as off-topic then do

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted to StackOverflow and got answers there.   It probably would have been better asked here originally, but now that it has answers there, it should be moved here with the answers rather than re-posted here.